# Ipad tableview and imageview

Tags: ipad

How to insert four tableview in a scrollview by pagination.i know how to do this ,but i need a image view as first page and then tableview as second,third and forth page.
Thankz in advance

```
_scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 1000, 460)];
    _scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    _scroll.pagingEnabled=YES;
    _scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000*5, 460);
    [_scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    CGFloat x=0;

    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x+10, 10, 750, 440) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        table.rowHeight = 120;  
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        table.delegate=self;

        //table.dataSource=self;
        [_scroll addSubview:table];
        [table release];
        x+=1000;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:_scroll];
    _scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    [_scroll release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the recommendation that UITableViews are not embedded inside scroll views as they are scrollviews in themself. So dont do this (not a joke).

You add the imageview with `addSubview:` just like the tableviews you want add. They are all `UIViews` and are all treated the same way.

So for a hypothetical scrollview with size (100,100) and imageview/tableviews of size (100,100)

```
imageview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
[scrollview addSubview:imageview];
tableview1.frame = CGRectMake(100,0,100,100);
[scrollview addSubview:tableview1];
tableview2.frame = CGRectMake(200,0,100,100);
[scrollview addSubview:tableview2];
tableview3.frame = CGRectMake(300,0,100,100);
[scrollview addSubview:tableview3];
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400,100);
scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: but i want pagination enabled,fist page is imageview then 4 tableviews.Is the code ok for that?

Comment: yes , a scrollview with paging enabled will stop on multiples of its bounds. But seriously dont put UITableViews in UIScrollViews

Comment: @sir,Warren Burton ,i give u my code sample which i put tableview in scroll with paging enabled please check is this code right or not

Comment: What you are dropping into the scrollView is a different width to the scrollView so the paging won't completely work how you might wish.

Comment: i edited the quiestion above,that is my code for paging scrollview with tableview,but i want imageview instead of tableview on 1st page then follws tableview.